# Broadcast receiver starts but crashes

Tags: android, eclipse, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I'm trying to make a BroadcastReceiver so when the device boots,the application starts checking for notifications.
My problem is that when I reboot my device , it shows me an alert dialog showing "Unfortunately TestBootReciever (My app name) has stopped".
Here is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testbootreciever"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name="com.example.testbootreciever.OnBootReceiver" 
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testbootreciever.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my java:

```
package com.example.testbootreciever;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

here is my logcat:this is for my Samsung Galaxy s3 & wallet crashed , another app called newsapp-which im developing - crashed as well.But not TestBootReciever - because I found the logcat after I tried the solution down there.

```
02-24 12:02:37.452: D/ExchangeService(610): Received deviceId from Email app: null
02-24 12:02:37.452: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and    retrying
02-24 12:02:42.540: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
02-24 12:02:42.550: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand,  startingUp = false, running = false
02-24 12:02:42.560: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
02-24 12:02:42.570: W/ActivityManager(285): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
 02-24 12:02:42.580: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
02-24 12:02:42.591: W/ActivityManager(285): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService  has leaked ServiceConnection  com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cdbdc0 that was originally  bound here
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cdbdc0 that was originally bound here
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-24 12:02:42.600: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610): null
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cdbdc0 that was originally bound here
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at   android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-24 12:02:42.610: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-24 12:02:42.610: W/ActivityManager(285): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41032840
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce7a30 that was originally bound here
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce7a30 that was originally bound here
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-24 12:02:42.630: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610): null
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce7a30 that was originally bound here
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-24 12:02:42.650: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-24 12:02:42.650: W/ActivityManager(285): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fa0498
02-24 12:02:45.270: E/ThrottleService(285): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-24 12:03:21.970: D/dalvikvm(389): GC_CONCURRENT freed 351K, 17% free 2913K/3480K, paused 82ms+6ms, total 159ms
02-24 12:03:27.631: D/ExchangeService(610): Received deviceId from Email app: null
02-24 12:03:27.631: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
02-24 12:03:32.710: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
02-24 12:03:32.730: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
02-24 12:03:32.730: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
02-24 12:03:32.740: W/ActivityManager(285): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
02-24 12:03:32.750: D/ExchangeService(610): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
02-24 12:03:32.760: W/ActivityManager(285): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d428b0 that was originally bound here
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d428b0 that was originally bound here
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
 02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-24 12:03:32.770: E/ActivityThread(610):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610): null
 02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d428b0 that was originally bound here
 02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
 02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
 02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
 02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
  02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
 02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
 02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
 02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
 02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
  02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):    at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
  02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
     02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
     02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
  02-24 12:03:32.870: E/StrictMode(610):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
  02-24 12:03:32.870: W/ActivityManager(285): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@411e0118
  02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d424b8 that was originally bound here
  02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d424b8 that was originally bound here
  02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
   02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):   at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
     02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
       02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):   at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
     02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
    02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
  02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):    at  com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
    02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
   02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):   at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
  02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):    at  com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
   02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):   at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
  02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
 02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
   02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 02-24 12:03:32.900: E/ActivityThread(610):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610): null
  02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d424b8 that was originally bound here
 02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
 02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
   02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):   at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
   02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):   at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
  02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):    at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
    02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
  02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-24 12:03:33.000: E/StrictMode(610):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-24 12:03:33.020: W/ActivityManager(285): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4107f1d0
02-24 12:03:33.031: D/dalvikvm(610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 431K, 19% free 2496K/3060K, paused 75ms+83ms, total 252ms
```

I'm running it on Samsung Galaxy s3 running android 4.1.2.
I also tried it on Nexus S emulator,the same problem.

After I installed it, I clicked it - launch manually - then I rebooted my device & the message above appeared.

I know that there are many questions asked about android broadcastReceiver,and I read most of them,but none helped.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: Please post your logcat error trace, without that we cannot find the root cause.

Comment: See my logcat above. Raghav Sood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as though `OnBootReceiver` is an inner class in `MainActivity`. This means you cannot reference it as `com.example.testbootreciever.OnBootReceiver`. Try using `com.example.testbootreciever.MainActivity$OnBootReceiver` instead. So your manifest looks like:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.testbootreciever.MainActivity$OnBootReceiver" 
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Alternatively, move `OnBootReceiver` into its own, individual class.

Comment: @user1967122 If there is a crash, there will be a stacktrace saying what cause it. Post that

Comment: I'll start an emulator,which my application is installed on it,& I'll watch the logcat and write it.. hold on please

Comment: Thanks..I restarted my s3 and it didn't crash